# removing similar html tags based on their inner text

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

I have 2 different script tags:

`<script>//</script>`
`<script>//data</script>`

I wanted to remove the first one. so I used the following:
`$("script").filter(":contains('//')").remove();`
but the line above removes both.
How can i remove the first only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:contains means anywhere in the string

This will remove it if it ONLY contains "//"

```
$("script")
  .filter(function () { return this.textContent.trim() === "//" })
  .remove();
```

To remove the first script that has a // you can use .eq

```
$("script")
  .filter(":contains('//')")
  .eq(0)
  .remove();
```

Comment: thank you so much ! I had to tweak it a little bit by changing it into $("script").filter(function () { return this.children[0].data === "//" }).remove();

Answer (score 0):

.filter() method is return an array. so if you want to delete the first one you must select like an array.

```
$("script").filter(":contains('//')")[0].remove();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).